# C++ I think my union may be producing undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, unions

I am using a union to represent rgb pixel data, so it can be accessed as a continual array of `uint8_t` or as individual rgb elements. (I think this is probably one of the few uses for unions.)

Something like this:

```
union PixelRGB
{
    uint8_t array[3];
    struct rgb
    {
        uint8_t b;
        uint8_t g;
        uint8_t r;
    };
};
```

I actually picked this code up from somewhere else online which suggested this as a potential use.

I asked a question a few minutes ago about a seperate issue but was told my union may produced UB.

I've read through [this](http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-rules-for-unions) and it does appear to indicate that if I read from a member which was not the last member to be written, then the result is UB...

My question is why?

My assumption (perhaps wrong?) is that in memory the union would be represented as:

```
b = array[0]
g = array[1]
r = array[2]
```

ie; each of these variables occupies exactly the same bytes (space/location/address) in memory, and therefore I would assume the line

```
g = 0xff;
```

would change the value of `array[1]` to be `0xff`.

Am I wrong? Why?

For arguments sake: C++ 14

Duplicate question is not duplicate: Linked question asks whether two structs inside a union is UB - not quite what I am asking here.

Comment: I have seen this exact structure multiple times today. What makes this question different from your other ones?

Comment: And C++ does not allow *type-punning* using unions.

Comment: Interesting point here: You are declaring a type, nested in the union, but the union doesn't contain a subobject of that declared type!

Answer (score 4):

> I've read through this and it does appear to indicate that if I read from a member which was not the last member to be written, then the result is UB...
>
> My question is why?

**Because the Standard says so<sup>1</sup>**. The Standard sometimes imposes on us (C++ developers) rules which allow implementations (compilers) to ignore edge cases and allow them to optimize for the nominal case. This is such a rule.

Some compiler may build a binary working as you expect. Some may produce a crashing executable. Some may do anything in between or seemingly random. *Undefined behavior is undefined*<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1)</sup>

> #### [`[class.union]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#1)
>
> In a union, a non-static data member is active if its name refers to an object whose lifetime has begun and has not ended ([basic.life]). At most one of the non-static data members of an object of union type can be active at any time, that is, the value of at most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time.

and

> #### [`[basic.life]/7`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#7)
>
> Similarly, before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, any glvalue that refers to the original object may be used but only in limited ways. [...] **The program has undefined behavior if**:
>
> - the glvalue is used to access the object, or
> - [...]

To make it easier to parse for humans, with the following context:

```
union { unsigned a; char b[sizeof(unsigned)]; } u;
u.a = 0;       // (1)
(void) u.b[0]; // (2) UB
```

On line marked `(1)`, `u.a` is now the active member of `u`. Per `[class.union]/1`, since only one non-static member of a union can be active at the same time, `u.b` is *not* active.

This means on line marked `(2)`, we access the value of an object whose lifetime has either not yet begun or already ended in a way making it undefined behavior per `[basic.life]/7`.

---

<sup>2)</sup>

> #### [`[defns.undefined]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.undefined)
>
> **undefined behavior**
> behavior for which this document imposes no requirements

Comment: Conversely, [\[basic.lval\]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11): "If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:[...] [(11.6)](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11.6) -- an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or non-static data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or contained union)". Conspicuously missing is a requirement to access unions _using_ the member matching the access type.

Comment: ... Further, I'm unclear on how [\[basic.life\]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#7) applies here, as the object in question is the _aggregate or union_, not its active member, and I know of nothing in the standard which states that an _access_, whether valid or invalid, should end an objects lifetime. Further still, [\[class.union\]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#1) immediately defines "active member" as referring to which type of data is _stored_ in the union. No mention is made to which types of data can be accessed, therefore leading back to [basic.lval]/11.

Comment: I did read it, several times, and again while writing this comment. I was indeed incorrect about the particulars of which object was "live". However, perhaps you could cite the verbiage which states that accessing a non-active member of a union ends the lifetime of the active member? Clearly such access cannot be _before_ said lifetime, as otherwise said member wouldn't _be_ active. In the absence of such verbiage, clearly [basic.life]/7 **cannot** apply as it explicitly refers to the periods between allocation and the lifetime beginning, and between the lifetime ending and reuse/release.

Comment: Further, [\[basic.lval\]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#6) would appear to apply to type-punning via _access_ through a union: "Whenever a glvalue appears as an operand of an operator that expects a prvalue for that operand, the lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, or function-to-pointer standard conversions are applied to convert the expression to a prvalue." ...

Comment: ... Thus we look to [\[[conv.lval\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.lval), particularly [(3.1)](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.lval#3.1) as the access in question appears not to run afoul of any of the restrictions in this section: "If T is cv std::nullptr_­t, the result is a null pointer constant ([conv.ptr]). [ Note: Since the conversion does not access the object to which the glvalue refers, there is no side effect even if T is volatile-qualified ([intro.execution]), and **the glvalue can refer to an inactive member of a union** ([class.union]). — end note ]" (emphasis added).

Comment: So why make an explicit note that an otherwise-unsafe access _is_ safe in one specific form if that particular form invokes UB in all contexts?

Comment: @pandorafalters I've added an explanation. Does it answer your questions?

Comment: I understand, yet still disagree, with both your reasoning and your conclusions.

Comment: @pando then please write an answer ;)

Comment: I don't think any versions of the C nor C++ Standard has ever made any reasonable effort to define accesses to aggregate members.  The early standards date to a time when it was easier for compilers to process some corner cases in useful fashion than to do anything else, and nobody thought it would really matter whether or not the Standard *actually* defined their behavior.  In your union example, the assignment to `u.a` uses a glvalue  of type `unsigned `to access the stored values of `u` and also e..g `u.b[0]`, and there is no circumstance when an `unsigned` lvalue is allowed...

Comment: ...to be used to access an object of type `union u`.  This wouldn't be a problem if the rules that were intended to say when things may alias were applied only for that purpose, and recognized that an access to via pointer/reference/glvalue that is freshly derived from another one *is* a reference to the latter glvalue, but for some reason compiler writers seem to prefer adding more complicated rules that still fail to allow for even the most basic scenarios like the `u.a` above.

Answer (score 2):

It's undefined behaviour, explicitly so in the standard. You can't write a union in one and read in another (expections apply) and get defined behaviour in C++.

However, it will also work on any compiler you're likely to come across, and if you are doing stuff with RGB values and pixels your code is likely tied to platform anyway so my advice is not to worry about it.

Comment: I'd rather `static_assert(&pixel.array[0] == &pixel.r)` and the same for the other two colours, so it at least fails to compile on platforms where this fails.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Compilers are much stricter about UB at compile time. I would expect that to fail even when this will work in practice.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I just [tried it](https://godbolt.org/z/bDLsps); GCC doesn't allow the `static_assert` even though it does explicitly allow type punning through unions as a language extension.

Comment: Check out https://godbolt.org/z/6Oiuds. You copied a bug from the original question (no instance of `PixelRGB::rgb` nested in the union). Also, you need to compare addresses, not values.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The problem is not just one of address overlapping. The problem is one of optimizations the compiler is allowed to perform. It seems to me that the compiler can assume a value will never change through a different member so it could keep a value in a register and fail to re-read its updated value from memory if it was written through a different member (for example).

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt it's guaranteed that those two things occupy the same memory location, so such a static assert would be pointless (even if it were legal)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the assumption may be compiler dependent. Therefore I have found this as an alternative solution:

```
class PixelRGB
{

    public:

    unsigned char array[3];
    unsigned char &r;
    unsigned char &g;
    unsigned char &b;

    PixelRGB()
        : r{array[2]}
        , g{array[1]}
        , b{array[0]}
    {
    }
}
```

You may have to watch your endian-ness. Such an obvious solution. It is essentially a software union. The disadvantage is this struct uses significantly more memory (unless the compiler can somehow optimize away the references?) - but this isn't a problem. Store data as `unsigned char[]` and then only use this for manipulation, which is what my intended purpose was.

Comment: There is no endianess to worry about! Endianess will not affect unsigned chars.

Comment: @purpletentacle When reading data you have to worry about rgb pixel order

Comment: @purpletentacle All I am saying is `r` might be `[0]` not `[2]`

Comment: Yes, RGB order is important! but that is not endianess

Comment: @purpletentacle that is what I mean by endianness - byte order

Comment: @user3728501: neither the order of the array, nor the order of the three RGB values is implementation defined. If there was an `unsigned int` alias this would come into it, but not in this case.

Comment: Also won't this approach produce  a far larger struct, rendering it useless for the likely intended use of representing an image through an array of pixels?